# Java - Error in While Calling StandardCharsets.UTF-8

Tags: java

I getting an error line under `StandardCharsets`. I have imported it, so I am not sure why I am getting the `StandardCharsets cannot be resolved to a variable` error.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Path;

public class Training
{
    
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(Path.of("text.txt"),StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        
        System.out.print(in);
    }
}
```

I am expecting to print the data in the `text.txt` file.

Comment: "**an** error"?

Comment: no "the error".

Comment: I was asking what the error message is...

Comment: Please see revision.

Comment: I would have thought this to be a duplicate. Yet I cannot find any existing Questions where "cannot be resolved to a variable" is caused by a lack of an `import`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need additional import

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
```